# Can I create a decimal ordered list in HTML without CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: html

I have been given an assignment to create an ordered list of the following type without CSS or javascript:

```
1.some text
  1.1 some text
  1.2 some text
2.some text 
  2.1 some text...
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely possible while only using HTML.

You can do this by using nested `<ol>` tags.

**Example:**

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**This will give the following result:**

> 1. 1. item 1
>    2. item 2
> 2. 1. item 3
>    2. item 4